# What would causes search to return incorrect results?

Tags: posts, customization, pages, search

Recently our site began no longer returning correct search results. When searching it returns one result that's unrelated to the inquiry. I've turned off all plugins and reverted back to a day when I thought it was working properly to no avail. What could possibly cause this to occur?

You can see in the image below that the result is not related to the inquiry.
[image]

Here's an example of a page with the title and terms related to the inquiry.
[image]

The front end also returns inaccurate results[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, out-of-the-box WordPress does not include taxonomies, such as tags and categories, in it's search, only post titles & content.

I'm sure this has always been the case, so I'm a little confused as to why it 'used to work'. Perhaps the pages have been modified, and used to contain the search terms themselves, but no longer do?

**UPDATE**: Taking a look at your `functions.php`, I see three possible troublemakers;

1. Line 572, `add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'query_post_type');`
2. Line 597, `add_filter('pre_get_posts','SearchFilter');`
3. Line 776, `add_filter('posts_groupby', 'group_by_post_type' );`

I suggest, one at a time, commenting out the line (prepend the line with `//`) and then testing a search. If there are no improvements, try all three commented out and work your way backwards. Either way you should be able to isolate the problem.

Also, two minor improvement suggestions (off-topic);

1. Remove the line `add_action('init', 'my_init_method');` (it's worthless)
2. Remove the two `update_option` calls at the top (unneccessary database writes on *every* request).

Comment: At the very minimum I should be seeing a result simply from the title or the text in the body. I'm not concerned about taxonomies or categories. The pages have not been changed in any drastic fashion.

Comment: Apologies, I'd only glanced at the screenshot. Try searching for "Support" - note the case. I've an inkling to the problem.

Comment: "Support" returns the same result, the products page.

Comment: I'm scratching my head here. What happens if you run a search on the front-end, i.e. `http://mysite.com/?s=support` ?

Comment: It returns incorrect result, I updated the post to show that information.

Comment: Switch your theme to Twenty Ten (or any other 'default' WordPress one) and try again. Themes can interfere as much as plugins, even on the backend.

Comment: Ok so it is absolutely my theme, what would cause that to happen?

Comment: Without code, all I can say is look for filters in your `functions.php` that affect post queries. Otherwise http://pastebin.com/ the contents of `functions.php` and send us the link, we'll find the culprit.

Comment: Awesome, really appreciate it. Let me know if you see anything else odd. http://pastebin.com/6UdUfzPX

Comment: Answer updated.

Comment: removing `add_filter('posts_groupby', 'group_by_post_type' );` totally worked. Thank you very much for the help